# Do `bindings` within a set have to be unique for a uniform?

Tags: glsl, vulkan

```
layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform sampler2D sampler;
layout (set = 0, binding = 0) uniform Test{
  mat4 m;
} test;
```

This compiles with `glslang` without any errors. I thought that bindings within a set have to be unique?

If this is indeed allowed, how would you send data to `sampler` and `test`?

```
typedef struct VkWriteDescriptorSet {
    VkStructureType                  sType;
    const void*                      pNext;
    VkDescriptorSet                  dstSet;
    uint32_t                         dstBinding;
    uint32_t                         dstArrayElement;
    uint32_t                         descriptorCount;
    VkDescriptorType                 descriptorType;
    const VkDescriptorImageInfo*     pImageInfo;
    const VkDescriptorBufferInfo*    pBufferInfo;
    const VkBufferView*              pTexelBufferView;
} VkWriteDescriptorSet;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the requirement Nicol Bolas quoted, there's a couple other relevant parts:

The [Valid Usage for VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-VkDescriptorSetLayoutCreateInfo-binding-00279) says:

> The `VkDescriptorSetLayoutBinding::binding` members of the elements of the `pBindings` array must each have different values.

That means you can't have a descriptor set layout that uses more than one variable with a particular (set,binding). So you also can't create a descriptor set or a pipeline that has more than one variable with the same binding. So even if the GLSL and SPIR-V are valid on their own, there's no way to use the variables or to disambiguate which one to use in Vulkan.

Section [13.2.2 Pipeline Layouts](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0-extensions/html/vkspec.html#descriptorsets-pipelinelayout) says:

> All resource variables statically used in all shaders in a pipeline must be declared with a (set,binding,arrayElement) that exists in the corresponding descriptor set layout and is of an appropriate descriptor type and includes the set of shader stages it is used by in stageFlags.

Since this ties SPIR-V variables in the pipeline's shaders to bindings in a descriptor set layout, the SPIR-V would be invalid to use in a Vulkan pipeline, since there would be no way to satisfy this requirement: you could satisfy it only for one of the variables that have the same (set,binding).

Answer (score 1):

Vulkan 1.0.58 clarifies this, declaring the above code to explicitly be illegal:

> It is valid for multiple shader variables to be assigned the same descriptor set and binding values, as long as all those that are statically used by the entry point being compiled are compatible with the descriptor type in the descriptor set layout binding.

There's pretty much no way that your descriptor set layout type can be compatible with both a `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_UNIFORM_BUFFER/_DYNAMIC` and `VK_DESCRIPTOR_TYPE_COMBINED_IMAGE_SAMPLER`. So this would fail to work.